# How can one pass values to a bus in Verilog without first making a wrapper bus?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, flipflop, quartus

I have just defined an SR flip flop, and I need to now define a D flip flop. I am going about this by using an SR flip flop within my D flip flop. However, because I used a bus for my S and R inputs on the SR ff, I don't know how to get D and D' into this bus (sr[1:0]).

I know that I could do this by creating another empty bus/array, but I am asking to see if this can be done more efficiently such as passing `[d, ~d]` to the constructor of the SR ff.

Current code:

```
module sr(q, qb, sr, rst, clk);
input [1:0] sr;
input rst, clk;
output q, qb;
reg q, qb;


always @(posedge clk) begin

if(rst==1) begin
q=0;
qb=1;
end else case(sr)
2'b00: begin q=q; qb=qb; end
2'b01: begin q=0; qb=1; end
2'b10: begin q=1; qb=0; end
2'b11: begin q=1'bx; qb=1'bx; end

default: begin end
endcase

end

endmodule
```

```
module df(q, qb, d, rst, clk);
input d, rst, clk;
output q, qb;

always @(posedge clk) begin

sr sr1(q, qb, [d, ~d], rst, clk);


end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the **concatenation** operator, which is expressed like this:  **{ , }**.

Only a small modification is needed to make your code work:

```
sr sr1(q, qb, {d, ~d}, rst, clk);
```

Comment: I changed it to use the concatenation operator as you are talking about but for some reason I'm still getting a syntax error. It says it is expecting a semi-colon on line 7 "near" the '(' which would be the one to the right of sr1 or the opening parenthesis for the constructor.

Comment: @Papu you shouldn't be instantiating you're module instance inside an `always` block.

Comment: @TomCarpenter You were right, that's what was causing the syntax error. It works just fine now.